# 押したボタンによって、次のページの背景画像を変えたいのですがうまくいきません。

Tags: swift4

<起こるエラー>
実行はできるのですが、一つ目のボタンを押してみると、
getimage.image = bin1と書いた部分に以下のようなエラーが表示されます。

```
Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

<補足>
ボタンにはtag付けをしています。

コード

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController ,UIActionSheetDelegate{


    @IBOutlet weak var getimage: UIImageView!

    //画像ファイルの定義 〜bin(数字)という名前に変更
    var bin1 = UIImage(named:"binsen1.jpg")!
    var bin2 = UIImage(named:"binsen2.jpg")!
    var bin3 = UIImage(named:"binsen3.png")!


    @IBAction func action(_ sender: UIButton) {
        switch sender.tag {
        case 1:
        //getimageというUIImageに画像を表示
            getimage.image = bin1
        case 2:
            getimage.image = bin2
        case 3:
            getimage.image = bin3

        default:break
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: 記載された症状は、`action(_:)`が実行された時点で、`getimage`が`nil`であることを表しています。`ViewController`のoutletが確実に接続されているか、再度確認してください。Xcode上では繋がっているように見えても、実際にはうまく行っていないことがあるので、一旦接続を解除してつなぎ直してみるといいでしょう。なお、タイトルには「次のページの背景画像」とありますが、次の画面に配置された`UIImageView`などをoutlet接続することはできないので何かの間違いでしょうか。ちなみに`UIImage(named:"...")!`に対応する画像がうまく取得できない場合には`!`のせいで、`ViewController`のインスタンス化の際にFatal Errorになりますから、今回の症状には合致しません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！ 別のページのUIImageViewとoutlet接続ができないことを知らなかったので、次の画面のUIImageViewと接続していました...。 そうなると、コーディングだけで画像表示できるようにするのがよいのでしょうか。　始めたばかりのため、アドバイスいただけると幸いです。

Comment: 次画面になにがしかのデータを渡したいのであれば、ある程度はコードを書いてやらないと仕方ありません。次画面のviewcontrollerのコードや画面遷移の設定などの情報をきちんと記載すれば、的確なアドバイスが得られるでしょう。当質問とは随分趣旨が離れてしまうので、別質問としていただいた方がいいかもしれません。

Comment: なるほど、そうですね。別に質問させていただくことにします。今回のご回答、誠にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

2つ目、3つ目のボタンを押したときの動作のみ期待通り動くのでしょうか？

2つ目、3つ目のボタンを押しても同じエラーが出るようでしたら、
`binsen1.jpg`から`binsen3.jpg`までのファイルがプロジェクトに追加され、プロジェクト設定の`Build Phase`→`Copy Bundle Resources`に、上記ファイルが含まれているか確認して下さい。

余談ですが、積極的に直す必要はありませんが、直した方がより良い所が2点ほど。

- `bin1` ~ `bin3`は`UIImage`の再代入をしないのであれば`let`の方がいいと思います
- 変数の宣言は、変数名の後ろに`: 型・クラス名`としてコーディング時に今、自分が宣言した変数はなにを格納するのか、型をしっかり書いた方がいいと思います

下の様な感じですね。

```
let bin1: UIImage = UIImage(named: "binsen1.jpg")!
let bin2: UIImage = UIImage(named: "binsen2.jpg")!
let bin3: UIImage = UIImage(named: "binsen3.jpg")!
```

Comment: ご回答と直した方がいい点のご指摘、誠にありがとうございます！
２つ目３つ目のボタンも同様にエラーが起きていました。
画像ファイルの場所を確認してみたところ、Copy Bundle Resourcesに入っていました。
そして、拡張子の記述をやめると同じように以下のようなエラーが出て、実行ができなくなってしまいました。
エラー：`Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: 済みません。`"binsen1.jpg"`は僕の間違いで、`.png`の時は拡張子を省略出来るけどそれ以外は拡張子は記述する必要があるみたいです。いずれにしろ、`UIImage(named: "ファイル名")`の所で、ファイルがないため`bin1`から`bin3`までに`nil`が入っているものと思われるので、デバッガーで`let`で`bin1`から`bin3`に値が入っているか？と、`getimage`が`nil`でないか、確認して下さい。

Comment: .png以外は記述が必要なのですね、ありがとうございます。
nilになっていないか確認してみます。